# Get Failure callback, after emit method is called- socket.io Java(Android) Client

Tags: socket.io-java-client

Currently, I'm using `mSocket.emit("1", json.toString());`. I have the `.on` method to receive the success callback. However, I don't know how to handle failure callbacks after `mSocket.emit("1", json.toString());` is called.